# How can I run iOS 4.3.3 developed apps on iOS5?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I upgraded to iOS5.

I am building an app using XCode4 targeting iOS 4.3.3.

Will I need to download XCode 4.2 to run my iOS 4.3.3 target?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot debug on your device without a version of XCode that expects iOS 5, but you can still install software using iTunes.

Build your app as if you were to distribute it for beta testing:

- Create a Distribution Certificate with your device UDID
- Build and Archive
- Share -> iOS App Store Package (.ipa)

Drop the resulting .ipa file into iTunes, then sync your iOS 5.0 device with iTunes.